# How do i read the Title property of a GDK.Window

Tags: c#, mono, gdk

I'm converting an .NET Windows application for Mono to run on Linux (Ubuntu). One of the features depends on a native library (user32.dll). The Mono guide that talks about conversion of applications ([Linux Platform Differences](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3a_Porting_Winforms_Applications#Linux_Platform_Differences)) suggests that one approach would be to modify this code.

I'm trying to use GDK to access the Title of a Gdk.Window that I had access through the property Gdk.Global.ActiveWindow. But I found this error at compile time:

```
Error CS0154: The property or indexer `Gdk.Window.Title` cannot be used in this context because it lacks the `get` accessor (CS0154) (GetActiveWindow)
```

If i remove the code that reads de `Title` property of activeW, everything works fine. There is another way to read this property?

Here my unit of work:

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using Gdk;
using System.Threading;

namespace GetActiveWindow
{
    class GdkApp : Gtk.Window
    {

        public static void Main ()
        {
            Application.Init ();
            new GdkApp ();
            Application.Run ();
        }

        public GdkApp () : base("Simple App")
        {
            SetDefaultSize (150, 150);
            ShowAll();
            while (true) {
                var activeW = Gdk.Global.ActiveWindow;
                Console.WriteLine("Active Window: {0}",activeW.Title); // Where my compile error happens.
                Console.WriteLine("Simple App Window: {0}",this.Title); // This code works perfectily.
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what does the code that you are using look like is thee something like this located in `GDK` `gtk_window_get_title`

Comment: @dj-kraze Sorry, forgot to attach my code.

Comment: does the `base` class have a `Title` property..? I am assuming you want to display or have show up in the console `Simple App`

Comment: Yes it has. The problem is that the `ActiveWindow` `Title` Property does not have the get accessor, only the set.

Comment: @dj-kraze What i'm trying to do is display the `Title` property of the window that has focus, but not only from my application, from the entire OS.

Answer (score 0):

I think that with Gdk is imposible. Try it with Wnck library giving to a C compiler this '-DWNCK_I_KNOW_THIS_IS_UNSTABLE' and works but with a warning: *Unhandled action type _OB_WM_ACTION_UNDECORATE*

Sorry I have used genie instead vala.

```
//valac *.gs --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg libwnck-3.0 -X '-DWNCK_I_KNOW_THIS_IS_UNSTABLE'

init
    Gtk.init(ref args)
    var ventana= new win()
    ventana.inicio()
    ventana.printinfo()
    Gtk.main()


class win:Gtk.Window

    won:weak GLib.List of Wnck.Window

    def inicio()

        var button= new Gtk.Button()
        button.clicked.connect(printinfo)
        this.add(button)
        this.show_all()

    def printinfo()
        won= Wnck.Screen.get_default().get_windows()
        won.foreach(allwin)

    def allwin(w:Wnck.Window)
        if w.is_skip_tasklist() or w.is_skip_pager()
            pass
        else
            print w.get_name()
```

Comment: Note: The program gets the name of all windows when the button is clicked.